# htaccess set max_execution_time for a path

Tags: php, apache, execution-time

I would like to set in my .htaccess `php_value max_execution_time 0` only for path that ends with a determine text, for example `\files\upload`

I'm using slim php framework

Comment: You cannot put conditional directives in your `htaccess` file (like `Location`), but you can put them in your vhost config or you can create separate htaccess files in the real directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### .htaccess file

`<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 0
</IfModule>`

You should put the htaccess file in that folder